# Extracting an array of non=sibling hash values from a nested data structure in perl

Tags: arrays, perl, data-structures, reference, nested

This is my data structure created by Data::Dumper->Dumper:

```
$VAR1 = {
          'name' => 'genomic',
          'class' => [
                     {
                       'reference' => [
                                      {
                                        'name' => 'chromosome',
                                        'referenced-type' => 'Chromosome'
                                      },
                                      {
                                        'name' => 'chromosomeLocation',
                                        'referenced-type' => 'Location'
                                      },
                                      {
                                        'name' => 'sequence',
                                        'referenced-type' => 'Sequence'
                                      },
                                      {
                                        'name' => 'sequenceOntologyTerm',
                                        'referenced-type' => 'SOTerm'
                                      }
                                    ],
                     }
                   ],
        };
```

(trimmed for clarity)

I would like to return a reference to an array of each name value under reference in a single line.

Currently I have

```
$class->[0]{reference}[0..3]{name}
```

but no avail.

Also this example has four sibling-hashes with indexes 0..3, how can I represent the whole array independent of the number of elements?

Answer (score 1):

There isn't an easy syntax to do that, unfortunately. You'll have to use map:

```
my $array_ref = [
    map { $_->{name} } @{ $class->[0]{reference} }
];
```

Then, if you dump out $array_ref, you'll see it contains:

```
$array_ref = [
          'chromosome',
          'chromosomeLocation',
          'sequence',
          'sequenceOntologyTerm'
        ];
```

If you need references to the original strings (not copies), you just need a backslash before `$_` (so it'd be `\$_->{name}` inside the map).

Comment: Bonus [perl5i](http://p3rl.org/perl5i) solution: `use perl5i::2; $VAR1->{class}[0]{reference}->map(sub { $_->{name} })` The expression returns  `[ 'chromosome', 'chromosomeLocation', 'sequence', 'sequenceOntologyTerm' ]`.

Answer (score 0):

`$class->[0]{reference}` is an array reference, so you have to dereference it with `@{}`:

```
@{$class->[0]{reference}}
```

Is the 'whole array', you can then use slice syntax on the end to get a part of it:

```
@{$class->[0]{reference}}[0..3]
```

From there you're working with an array of hashrefs, so you'll have to iterate over it with `for` or `map`.